# Screen Not Updating Until Home Button Pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I started getting a strange bug recently. I am converting my app from iPhone to iPad. It all seemed to be going well until I noticed that all my buttons and switches stopped working. When my app launches everything loads up fine (on both platforms). Then when you try a button the app appears frozen. Nothing happens at all. When you press the Home button all the changes you made (but did not see) are quickly displayed just before returning home. If you reopen the app (without quiting it) all buttons work just perfect. But on initial launch everything is broken.

Has anyone had this happen before? All I changed from the old working version was which xib gets displayed (iphone or ipad).

Comment: Suggestion: pause it in the debugger while it's not responding, see if the main thread is blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have fixed it. The elaborate process of determining which xib to use was apparently the problem. Going back to simply using

```
[self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

and relying on naming conventions to pick the xib was enough to fix it.